# How do I detect that text have been deleted by a track change request?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache-poi to read word files, and it is working.

I read the document text using a list of XWPFRun instances, and that is working fine.

But if track change is enabled for the document, I also get XWPFRun instances for text which have been deleted, if the delete have not been accepted. And I would like not to include this text.

So is there a way to detect track change status for a XWPDRun node, or even better a way to parse the document as if all track changes were accepted?

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported by `XWPFRun`. But we could determine whether there are text runs marked as deleted.

Normal text run's `XML` looks like:

```
<w:r>
 <w:t>Lorem</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Deleted text runs look like:

```
<w:del w:id="0" w:author="axel" w:date="2020-04-23T18:57:00Z">
 <w:r w:rsidDel="00C63AEB">
  <w:delText>ipsum</w:delText>
 </w:r>
</w:del>
```

So deleted runs are within a `del` element. But this is tricky to get.

But while normal text run's text is in a `t` element, it is in a `delText` element for deleted text runs. So `XWPFRun.getText(0)` will return `null` for deleted text runs, because this only traverses the `t` elements of the run. `XWPFRun.text()` or `XWPFRun.toString()` will return the text of the deleted runs too, because those methods traverses all elements which contain text in the run.

Furthermore, deleted text runs have `rsidDel` attribute in it's `CTR` object while getting that attribute from not deleted runs will get `null`.

And furthermore, `getDelTextList` from `CTR` of a text run will return a empty list for not deleted runs, but will return a filled list for deleted runs.

Example to detect deleted runs from a `WordExample.docx`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordReadDeletedRuns {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "./WordExample.docx";

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));
  for (IBodyElement bodyElement : document.getBodyElements()) {
   if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
    for (IRunElement runElement : paragraph.getIRuns()) {
     if (runElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
      XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun)runElement;
      System.out.println("Text run found: " + run.text());
      System.out.println(run.getText(0)); // null for deleted runs
      System.out.println(run.getCTR().getRsidDel()); // null for not deleted runs, byte[] for deleted runs
      System.out.println(run.getCTR().getDelTextList().size()); // empty list for not deleted runs, filled list for deleted runs
     }
    }
   }
  }
  document.close();
 }
}
```