# Apache POI XWPF conversion to HTML : How to identify text that has revision/track changes (ins/del)?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to convert Word document to HTML. This specific Word document has "Track changes" turned on in MS Word. This means that if in the Word document, there is some text that has been deleted by a user, MS Word will do a strikethrough on that deleted text and add a comment that "XYZ" user deleted this text.

Now, when I look at the OOXML for the text I see below structure:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="168813AD" w14:textId="5277CBBF" w:rsidR="00575536" w:rsidRDefault="00575536" w:rsidP="00575536">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:pStyle w:val="Body1"/>
              <w:spacing w:before="120" w:after="60"/>
              <w:jc w:val="both"/>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:snapToGrid w:val="0"/>
                <w:color w:val="auto"/>
                <w:sz w:val="20"/>
              </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="001D5C8C">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:snapToGrid w:val="0"/>
                <w:color w:val="auto"/>
                <w:sz w:val="20"/>
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t xml:space="preserve">Some text </w:t>
            </w:r>
             <w:del w:id="1" w:author="XYZ" w:date="2020-06-10T20:48:00Z">
              <w:r w:rsidRPr="001D5C8C" w:rsidDel="00E231AF">
                <w:rPr>
                  <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
                  <w:snapToGrid w:val="0"/>
                  <w:color w:val="auto"/>
                  <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:delText>This text is deleted</w:delText>
              </w:r>
            </w:del>
          </w:p>
```

Here I see <w:del> tag that includes the character run for the deleted text.

Now, when "visitRun" method is called for this character run that includes deleted text, how do I identify that this character run contains deleted text. I thought that I can find out by getting its parent but when I run the below code I do see that parent of this character run is a paragraph and not "w:del".

Is there a way to identify that a character run contains deleted text?

```
 @Override
    protected void visitRun( XWPFRun run, boolean pageNumber, String url, Object paragraphContainer )
        throws Exception
    {

        if(run.getParent() instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
            log.debug("Parent is paragraph");
        }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392640/how-do-i-detect-that-text-have-been-deleted-by-a-track-change-request/61393754#61393754

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter. Initially I used rsidDel and if its not null, then I would skip the character run to get rid of the deleted text. However, it did not work every time. I have some Word documents that have character runs with rsidDel non-null and they have some text in <w:t> tags. So, I observed that I was losing some legitimate text. Then I used size of DelTextList and that worked. So, that's what I am going to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using size of DelTextList did the trick for me. Here is the solution (hoping it helps someone):

```
    @Override
    protected void visitRun( XWPFRun run, boolean pageNumber, String url, Object paragraphContainer )
        throws Exception
    {
        //Sometimes Word documents have "Track changes" tunrned ON. 
        //In that case, you will see that the deleted text will be marked with a strikethrough but not really deleted. 
        //We don't want to display deleted text. So, we need to skip the character run for such deleted text.
        
        if(run.getCTR().getDelTextList().size()>0) {
            return;
        }
        
        ......
        ....
        //do work for non-deleted character runs
    }
```